# How to deduce l' = Ex or l' = Fx using the epipolar constraint?

Tags: computer-vision, slam, projective-geometry

How to deduce **l' = Ex**  using the epipolar constraint?

Where **l'** is the epipolar line, **E** is the essential matrix and **x** is the projected point in the image plane.

I understood that according to the epipolar constraint (all 3 vectors lie on the same plane) we can write:

> **x**.[**T**x]**R** **x**' = 0
>
> **E** = [**T**x]**R**
>
> **x**.**E** **x**' = 0

but I didn't find yet in the literature how to prove that Ex' is equal to the epipolar line equation in order to deduce following:

> **l**' = **E** **x**.

Thank you in advance.